# RTSP audio stream playback speed with vlcj

Tags: java, libvlc, vlcj

Is there any way, or possible workaround to set the playback speed of an RTSP audio stream in vlcj? I faced the problem that libvlc only handles 2x, 3x, 4x rates on streams, and I cannot find a solution it.

My stream provider is live555 media server that supporting multiple clients through tcp from a k8s pod. Other media players, like smplayer can play back my stream with different speed properly, in both faster and slower ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the culprit is in fact the media server. It seems like it's only supports the whole value rate settings (2x, 3x ...32x).

The "working" players were missleading because they handle the speed in the client side, that is why they can work. But as you can probably tell, this approach has a big impact on performance.

By using wireshark, it can be clearly seen that vlc tries to send the rate value in the `Scale` header to ask the server for faster/slower playback, but it responds with a rounded setting (if 1,5 gets sent, than it answers with 2). So my assumption that libvlc not supporting it was wrong.

The other players do not communicate the rate setting to the server.

[RTSP standard - Scale overview](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-56)

Answer (score 1):

For playback speed, the only option available in the LibVLC API is this:

```
libvlc_media_player_set_rate(mp, rate);
```

This is exposed in vlcj like this:

```
mediaPlayer.controls().setRate(rate);
```

You can use fractional values, so 0.5 is half speed, 1.25, 1.5 etc should all work.

This works generally for media playback, but whether this works for your particular case of RTSP with live555 I do not know - it either works or it doesn't, there's no alternative.

Comment: Thanks. I meant slower playback by negative, but that was not very clear by me, I'm sorry. I know about the rate setting, and it works like a charm on file based playbacks. It partially works with streams, with only support for the 2x, 3x, 4x rates specifically. That is why I'm desperately looking for a workaround to apply the whole possible rate scale to my stream playback.

Comment: Well unfortunately I don't think what you want to achieve is possible with vlcj/LibVLC. Maybe this is a limitation of Live555, but I don't know. - oh but I see you mention other media players work, so it's not that.